# Database for windows phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to create a database with Kitchen Recipes for example. So from my computer I add recipes and when someone with windows phone access the app should get the last recipes from the online database.

I am new in this and I only worked with mysql databases, so what kind of online database I should create for my application recipes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest taking look at the [Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) - these are designed specifically for mobile apps - simple db access, user management + lot more. You can find even sample project there with online TODO list, that could be good start point for your Kitchen Recipes app. The drawback here might be the monthly price.
If you want something cheaper, I'd recommend using [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) + [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org), hosted on Azure Website using the free plan. Here you only need to pay for the DB, that could be as few as 5$/month.

Comment: So in conclusion I must have a subscribe for a database.

Comment: If you want online database for your app, you need either your own server, or hosted solution somewhere. The mentioned Azure solution is the most convenient in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is available for WP and store apps.
This will allow you to have a local db on the device and allow users to use the app offline.
Just nuget it into your project, should be easy to use with the documentation online.

Comment: And if the application should connect for a online database to download new recipes?

Comment: See Martins answer; If you want to build a serious app, you have do more than just run some database. Azure Mobile Services, or any other provider like that will supply you with all your needs.